# How can I send c++ template to a wrapped element in parameter pack?

Tags: c++

now I have a special requirement.

1. the quantity of parameters handled by the function is not constant, so I have to use parameter pack in C++
2. the parameter is `std::pair<std:string, template>`, but different argument has different type of template, so the args would be like `std::pair<std::string, int>, std::pair<std::string, bool>, ...`. Actually, I need to evaluate the type of each argument and perform different branch by the type. And in C++ only template can transfer typename as argument.
3. an iterable class would be one of input arguments, so I hope to use the size of this argument instead of the quantity of variable parameters.

so the function would be similar like this:

```c++
template<typename... T>
template<typename pair_t> std::pair<std::string, T>
std::vector<ret_class> my_fun(const iterable_class &in_obj, pair_t &...type)
{
    std::vector<ret_class> ret;
    int i=0;
    for(auto arg:type) // ergodic all variable parameters, but I hope to use the iterable_class.size() as the index limit.
    {
        ret.push(handle_fun<arg.second>(iterable_class[i])); // arg.second would change the behavior of handle_fun
        ++i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

but it can't pass compile.

Can anybody help me to clarify this issue?

Comment: Even accepting that what you show is pseudocode, I don't understand what it's trying to do. So `type` is a parameter pack; it's a sequence of objects, not a sequence of types (`T...` would be a sequence of types). Then `arg` is one of those objects, and `arg.second` is another object - yet you are passing it to some function template as if it were a type. What's the declaration of `handle_fun`? Is the value of `arg` actually used for anything, or just its type? By `iterable_class[i]`, do you mean `in_obj[i]` (since `iterable_class` is a type, `iterable_class[i]` doesn't make sense)?

Comment: I would recommend you try to show something as close to a [mcve] as you can get; show the functions that `my_fun` should call, and an example of how `my_fun` itself would be called. In your attempt to make the example more abstract, you removed a bit too much detail, to the point where it stopped making sense.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `zip` operation. Given a parameter pack `T0...Ti`, you want to create a parameter pack `std::pair<std::string, T0> ... std::pair<std::string, Ti>`.

The declaration would be straightforward:

```
template<typename... T>
std::vector<ret_class> my_fun
    (const iterable_class &in_obj, std::pair<std::string, T>&...type)
{ /****/ }
```

`std::pair<std::string, T>&` is a *pattern*  containing the template pack identifier `T`, so it's expanded.

The `for(auto arg:type)` bit is more puzzling. You can't loop over a heterogeneous set of arguments. What type would `auto` even deduce?

It might just be easier to write this recursively

```
template<typename HEAD, typename... Tail>
std::vector<ret_class> my_fun
    (const iterable_class &in_obj, std::pair<std::string, HEAD> head, Tail&...tail)
{
   auto in_head = iterable_class.front();
   iterable_class.pop_front()
   auto ret = my_fun(iterable_class, tail...);
   ret.push_front(handle_fun<HEAD>(in_head));
   return ret;
}
}
return ret;
```

Comment: actually I tried to use `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end` to ergodic the variable arguments, but you know it's not safe, because `va_list` would not detect `va_end` automaticly, this is the reason why I hoped to use `in_obj.size()` as the limit range. Your answer based on recursive method is really smart! I like it. Thank you very much.